# Show that this function is in $L_1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let's say that function $f\in[0,T]$ is in a class $C$ when 
$$
f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{x^\alpha}
$$
where $0\leq \alpha<1$ and $g(x)$ is continuous on [0,T].

Then, it is trivial to show $C \subset L_1[0,T] $.

My question is that converse is also correct? (that is, $C=L_1[0,T]$)

If so, how to prove it?

If not, what is one of counterexamples?

Thank you!

Comment: This is obviously not correct, unless I'm misinterpreting something? What if you pick any discontinuous function in $L^1$?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true.
$L^1(0,T)$ contains discontinuous functions.